# landscape uiscrollview vertical iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

My interface and oriented in landscape mode. In my view, I have a form for recording with many `UITextField`.

The component `UIScrollView` comes moves only horizontally and not vertically. I would like the component `UIScrollView` only moves vertically to show all my `UITextField`, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `contentSize` property of the UIScrollView.

If your `UIScrollView` is 480/568 pixels wider (the width of the screen in landscape mode), then you can do this:

```
// Get the content height of the form (scrollview)
int scrollableHeight=700; // You can give accurate value by calculating last textfields frame position in form
CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(480, scrollableHeight);
[scrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
```

Now `UIScrollView` will only scroll vertically, because it can already display everything horizontally in landscape orientation.